# Create a weighted graph based on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, weighted-graph

consider a data frame like this:

| id | source | Target | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 1 |
| 2 | A | C | 2 |
| 3 | A | D | 3 |
| 4 | A | E | 4 |

I want to depict a graph with networkX which shows us two things:
1-Node with more connections has a larger size, respectively.
2-Edge with more weight has a thicker line in between.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the `edge_attr` to Weight when we create the Graph [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) then when we draw the graph we can [`get_edge_attributes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_edge_attributes.html) and pass that as the `width` of whatever drawing operation.

For `node_size` we can use [`nx.degree`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.degree.html) to get the Degree from the Graph:

```
nx.degree(G)

[('A', 4), ('B', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 1)]
```

We can then scale up the degree by some factor since these values are going to be quite small. I've chosen a factor of 200 here, but this can be adjusted:

```
[d[1] * 200 for d in nx.degree(G)]

[800, 200, 200, 200, 200]
```

All together it can look like:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df,
    source='source',
    target='Target',
    edge_attr='Weight'  # Set Edge Attribute to Weight Column
)

# Get Degree values and scale
scaled_degree = [d[1] * 200 for d in nx.degree(G)]
nx.draw(G,
        # Weights Based on Column
        width=list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'Weight').values()),
        # Node size based on degree
        node_size=scaled_degree,
        # Colour Based on Degree
        node_color=scaled_degree,
        # Set color map to determine colours
        cmap='rainbow',
        with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: weighted and coloured graph on degree]

---

Setup Used:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'source': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'Target': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'Weight': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})
```

Comment: thank you what about the size of nodes based on a degree?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the first time. I've updated my answer to include `node_size` based on degree.

Comment: and how can we define a color map based on the degree?

Comment: Same deal as node_size, just set node_color to the scaled degree and specify a `cmap`. See the edits.